# HashSet adding duplicates

Tags: collections, hashset

I am working on hashmaps . It do not allow duplicates but in this program it added three items according to me it should add only one bcz rest are same.

```
 import java.util.*;
public class WrappedString {
private String s;
public WrappedString(String s) { this.s = s; }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<Object> hs = new HashSet<Object>();
    WrappedString ws1 = new WrappedString("aardvark");
    WrappedString ws2 = new WrappedString("aardvark");
    String s1 = new String("aardvark");
    String s2 = new String("aardvark");
    System.out.println(hs.add(ws1));    //true
    System.out.println(hs.add(ws2));    ////true
    System.out.println(hs.add(s1)); //true
    System.out.println(hs.add(s2)); //false
    System.out.println(hs.size());//3 } }
```

Comment: what is this class `WrappedString`? HashSet depends upon `equals()` method to avoid duplicates. If your class does not override that, then you may get unpredictable results

Comment: @zencv there is no need to overide equals() method as it is already available to all classes because this method is defined in Object() class

Comment: @DishaJain Exactly Object implements equals and it determines those two objects are not equal.

Comment: @DishaJain: The default implementation of equals in Object does not compare for logical equality, rather only for object identity. If that is what you want, fine -- with the effect that any Set implementation that depends upon equals will treat them as different objects.  If you want two different objects to be treated as **same**, then provide your own implementation of equals and hashCode

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because ***WrappedString*** not working like "normal" ***String***. Then I recommend you use String.

It will **return false**:

```
new WrappedString("test").equals(new WrappedString("test"))
```

It will **return true**:

```
new String("aardvark").equals(new String("aardvark"))
```

If the result returned false, the HashSet will add like a new item.

Or, if you preffer don't change to String, you can override the equals and hashSet of WrappedString determining where is difference when it will be compared, doing something like this:

```
public class WrappedString {
    private String s;

    public WrappedString(String s) {
    this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        WrappedString ws = (WrappedString)obj;
        return this.s.equals(ws.s);
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.s.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question:

> System.out.println(hs.add(ws1)); //true
>
> System.out.println(hs.add(ws2));////true
>
> System.out.println(hs.add(s1)); //true

The reason is when you call `add` method on `HashSet`, the `element` you want to add is checked with existing `elements` of the `Set` using `equals()` method. Here `ws1` is not equal to `ws2` and also none of them is not equal to `s1`. So you see `true` three times.

Comment: Then in case of TreeSet why it not works public class Drink implements Comparable {
 public String name;
 public int compareTo(Object o) {
return 0;
 }
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static void main(String arg[]) {
 Drink one = new Drink();
  Drink two = new Drink();
  one.name= "Coffee";
   two.name= "Tea";
  TreeSet set = new TreeSet();
 System.out.println(set.add(one)); //true
   System.out.println(set.add(two));//false


}Here also both should be inserted as they are unique objects